# What 4xx HTTP return code should be used for private API error responses?

Tags: http, rest, http-headers

I'm designing a REST API. What response should a server send to mean "I've got your request, parsed it and it's valid, but I'm not not going to process it because you didn't provide enough globs."

IANA are never going to allocate a 4xx error code for this when there's only 100 possible errors. I've looked over the 4xx list on wikipedia and they all have specific meanings, none meaning a general-purpose error for private APIs to use.

What should a server do when the client fails to provide enough globs?

**UPDATE**
I don't think 400 is the right one. RFC2616 says:

> 10.4.1 400 Bad Request
>      The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>      syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>      modifications.

This error seems to be intended for more fundamental errors of protocol rather than the class of error I'm thinking of. However, many people seem to (ab)using this code for this purpose anyway.

Comment: what about error 550 ? I just posted a question on something similar at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525799/proper-use-of-http-error-codes-550-why-is-it-5xx-instead-of-4xx

Comment: 422, suggested by http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2434-HTTP-Status-Codes-For-Invalid-Data-400-vs-422.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

400 is a generic status code that is intended to capture a whole range of client errors.  Use the "reason phrase" or the response body to further qualify the reason for the error.

Comment: Thanks Darrel. The RFC lists a specific meaning to this error code, but I have (like you I suspect) seen it (ab)used. Updated question.

Comment: @billpg The description in RFC2616 was overly constraining and misunderstood which is why in the latest spec update it was changed to say "The server cannot or will not process the request, due to a client error (e.g., malformed syntax)." http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-19#section-7.4.1

Comment: That seems to cover it. Have a green tick.