# HttpResponseMessage Create HttpStatusCode 550

Tags: c#, rest, api, http

At Http Response Common there is [550 Error](https://www.smartlabsoftware.com/ref/http-status-codes.htm), but I can not find it at [HttpStatusCode Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
JavaScriptSerializer sr = new JavaScriptSerializer();
OTPOutError_Model oError = new OTPOutError_Model();
oError.message = "Business exception. ";

var httpContent = new StringContent(sr.Serialize(oError), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.HttpVersionNotSupported) { ReasonPhrase = "550", Content = httpContent };
throw new HttpResponseException(msg);
```

How can I return my Response Status 550? Is there any update of the enumeration?

At the sample code, I use 505 / HttpStatusCode.HttpVersionNotSupported. What I need is 550 instead of 505.

Comment: Is this a WebApi controller or a normal controller?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525799/proper-use-of-http-error-codes-550-why-is-it-5xx-instead-of-4xx). 550 is not even a proper code

Comment: WebApi Controller, @DiskJunky  Thanks

Comment: Also see [List of HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors). There's no official 550 error

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thank you Sir